# Jquery Selection option not working with switch and case

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, switch-statement, background-color

I try to create a select were you can choose a color to change the background. I wanted to accomplish this with a switch and case , but it doesn`t seem to work.

This is my html:

```
<select id="categorie">
    <option value="1">blue</option>
    <option value="2">red</option>
    <option value="3">green</option>
</select>
```

and this is my jquery:

```
$('#categorie').change(function(){

 var val = $(this).val();

switch (val) {
    case 1: $("#categorie").val( 1 );

    $('body').css('background-color','blue')
    break;
    case 2: $("#categorie").val( 2 );
    $('body').css('background-color','red')
    break;
    case 3: $("#categorie").val( 3 );
    $('body').css('background-color','green')
    break;}
});
```

Comment: have you tried string value? `case "1":` for example

Comment: or `var val = +$(this).val();` which convert valid numeric string to number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `parseInt` as `.val()` function returns string value by default.

So change your code as

```
 var val = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m3tX7/1/)

Comment: Thanks this seems to work, but it only works on fiddle. When i use it on my own websiet it doesnt work .